# Xcode : iPhone Simulatorをインストールできない

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Xcode7.0.1にて、iPhone Simulator8.2をインストールしようとしているのですが、
進捗が50%程度まで進んだところで、

"Could not download and install iOS 8.2 Simulator. パッケージをインストールするには、認証が必要です。"
[image: エラー発生時]
というダイアログが表示され、先に進むことができません。

・Xcodeの設定画面で、AppleIDは設定登録済みです。
・Simulatorのインストール開始時に、インストール許可確認のダイアログが表示されて、パスワードを入力しています。
・iOS 8.4 Simulatorも試しましたが、同様の状況でした。

原因、もしくは対策を教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 情報共有です。

Xcode Version 7.0.1にてiOS 8.4 Simulatorのインストール成功しました。
インストール開始時にパスワード入力画面が1度出たのみで、それ以降はノータッチで完了しました。

MacのOSはYosemite(10.10.5)です。

何かの参考になりましたら。